# How to create Spark activity to run Scala script on HDInsight?

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, azure-data-factory, azure-hdinsight

I want to execute Scala script using HDInsight. Below article describes running py script but did not mention abt Scala. I followed the article (instead of py file, uploaded Scala file) but Azure DataFactory failed to execute with error message:

```
({
    "errorCode": "2312",
    "message": "Spark job failed, batch id:4",
    "failureType": "UserError"
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-spark

Comment: If you want to run Scala scripts using Spark cluster, you can use Databricks activity rather than HDInsight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute spark code written in scala then you have to call Jar file
. If it is too complicated then you can also use databricks notebook. Let me know in case you face issue

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your problem you'd need to

1. Open your pipeline in ADF
2. Click on your spark activity
3. Go to script/jar, open Advanced
4. Set Debug Information for your activity to
   Always.

Though you be able to view logs after pipeline failed. Adf will provide you url to your logs. It'll be on the linked storage in the **log** dir in the root of your jar.

Examine logs to understand what causes your spark app to fail.
[See image from ADF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnB50.png)